How does react-native-mmkv achieve synchronus while being on react-native old architecture?
we are using react native version 0.71 with old architecture and when we experimented with react-native-mmkv we found that, it's fast and syncrhonous, we are curious to know how is it synchronous when it is on old architecture as it uses bridge to communicate.

react-native-mmkv V2 uses what they call "JSI C++ API" to bind C++ methods to JS, which is available even on old architecture.
React Native JSI provides an API to access native (swift/kotlin) methods and objects directly from JS, without using C++.
More info here: https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/91#issuecomment-1088011119
